# How do I check if a property exists in an object/dictionary?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

I'm iterating over an array of words and trying to stuff them in an object literal so I can assign the value of how many times those words occur to each word in the literal/dictionary. The problem is I need to check to make sure that word hasn't already been added into my literal. I tried using `in` to check if the property exists in the literal but it's throwing an error:

`Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'We' in undefined`

Here's problematic function:

**I commented the line that's causing the problem**

```
function wordCountDict(filename) {
   wordCount = {};
   inputFile = fs.readFile( root + filename, 'utf8', function( error, data ) {  
      if(error) {
         console.log('error: ', error) 
         return false;
      }

      var words = data.split(" ");
      for (i in words) {

         if(words[i] in wordCount) {  // This is where the problem occurs
            wordCount[words[i]]++;
         } else {
            wordCount[words[i]] = 1;
         }
         console.log(words[i]);
      }

   });
}
```

I'm coming from python and this was always the best/easiest way to achieve this, but javascript doesn't seem to agree.

How would I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: I can't see how you'd get that error message unless you're destroying the `wordCount` object before the asynchronous `readFile` callback has run.

Comment: Does `if(wordCount[words[i]])` give same error?

Comment: There clearly is an object, and using `in` to check for keys in an object shouldn't fail, and when it says the object is undefined, something else is going on here that we're not seeing.

Comment: Do you really mean for `wordCount` to be a global variable?

Comment: what about var before wordCount ?

Comment: A [**quick test**](http://jsfiddle.net/pRnaM/) seems to be working fine, and even if the variable is global, it's reset to an empty object on the first line of the function, so something must be overwriting the global while the async file reading takes place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare `wordCount` as a local variable to that function. It is probably getting overwritten elsewhere:

```
function wordCountDict(filename) {
    var wordCount = {};
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, watch out for those global variables. Easy to accidentally create them in javascript (especially if you are used to python)

Comment: @Scotty: Consider running your code in strict mode. This catches some common mistakes. If your code is in a node module, put `"use strict";` at the top of the module. There are some slight behavior differences that will come with strict mode, but I think they're for the better.

Comment: @Scotty if you're interested in learning more about how variables work in javascript, this is a really good read: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: cookie monster, not all of strict mode differences are better, and it's generally a bad advice to turn it on without any understanding what it does

Comment: @alex: I said *"I think they're for the better"*. It's my opinion. I don't know of any difference where I didn't think it was an improvement. *(The exception perhaps being the removal of `with`, which IMO is a little overkill.)* Considering that OP doesn't know the basics of the language, clearly there's some learning to do either way.

Comment: There are dozens of situations where strict mode is harmful, see [this article](http://webreflection.blogspot.ru/2011/06/es5-and-use-strict.html)..

Comment: @alex: Absolutely none of the examples in that article could be used to demonstrate that strict mode is "harmful". Strict mode does throw errors in some cases, and change behaviors in others... and that's the point! That doesn't make it harmful. It just tightens up the language a bit to block old, and arguably poor code. If a person doesn't like the changes, they don't need to use it. But calling it "harmful" is flat out silly.

Comment: How can a person like or don't like the changes if he don't know what the changes are?

If you know javascript well, by all means make a choice and put strict directive if you want. But if somebody doesn't know javascript, he should definitely not restrict himself to a very questionable subset of the language.

Comment: @alex: Dude, I'm not saying he shouldn't learn the ramifications of using strict mode. I never said that. I did say that OP has a lot to learn either way. I was responding to your dubious "harmful" claim. And it's your *opinion* that he shouldn't restrict himself to strict mode, and it's also your *opinion* that it's "questionable". I can understand that people have different opinions on whether or not to use it. But to make such blanket claims as though you're expressing statements of fact and not opinion is probably more harmful to a beginner than anything.

Comment: "harmful" claim refers to a fact that once strict mode is turned on, it can't be turned off per-function if you don't need it.

Comment: @alex: Alright, well your description of "harmful" was to point me to a blog post written by someone who spelled out specific changes he doesn't like, and I don't see where that point is mentioned. As my original comment implied, it can be defined per NodeJS module by putting it at the top of the module code.

Comment: @alex strict mode can't be "turned off" per function, but it can be "turned on" per function. See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#Strict_mode_for_functions

Comment: @atdrago, there is always some moron who tries to use your application with `node --use_strict`, get an error at first `0777`, and demand it to be removed claiming that the application doesn't work. Saw that multiple times.

Answer (score -2):

This is a bad idea

```
for (i in words) {
```

do not use a for loop to loop through an array! If something is added to the array prototype it will be checked.

```
  var words = data.split(" ");
  for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {

     if(words[i] in wordCount) {
```

Next thing, is readFile is asynchronous. If code outide of it resets wordCount to an undefined value, you can get this error. You are better off using a local variable and setting the global value when the looping is done. Also that `return false` does NOTHING inside the readFile.

```
function wordCountDict(filename) {
   var tempWordCount = {};
   var inputFile = fs.readFile( root + filename, 'utf8', function( error, data ) {  
      if(error) {
         console.log('error: ', error) 
         return false;
      }

      var words = data.split(" ");
      for (var i = 0; i<words.length; i++) {

         if(words[i] in wordCount) {  // This is where the problem occurs
            wordCount[words[i]]++;
         } else {
            wordCount[words[i]] = 1;
         }
         console.log(words[i]);
      }

      wordCount = tempWordCount;  //set the global variable equal to the local value

   });
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's bad form, but this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @jfriend00: It actually probably is the answer. I think OP has marked the wrong use of `in` in the question.

Comment: for-in loops should work on arrays, even if it's generally not a good idea.

Comment: @jfriend00: Then again, maybe not. There's no reason `words` would be `undefined` either, and the error message suggests it is indeed the `wordCount` object.

Comment: And it is amazing to see my "edited" answer was the actual solution. Code has so many issues...

Comment: Oh please. You *corrected* your answer after many comments on this page. I think you know that your answer originally had nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: @cookiemonster Making ~60K in rep, I do not copy. I rarely read other answers when I post. When I edited it, there was only 2 other answers. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -2):

If all you would like to do is check for existance in the object, you can use this:

```
if(typeof wordCount[words[i]] === 'undefined'){
    ...
}
```

I would not recommend just using `if(wordCount[words[i]])` because technically there could be a property of the object that exists but evaluates to false.

Note that in Javascript doing something like myObject.something is equivalent to myObject['something'] on an object, and that when you use myObject['somethingElse'] you are basically just dynamically adding members to the object. In Javascript, objects can be used like Python dictionaries, but they really aren't the same thing.

Comment: Just like most the other answers, this is wrong too, or at best off topic. The issue was with `wordCount` being `undefined`. Yours will fail with a *TypeError*.